Using cat() inside warning() puts the message before the warning
I used cat() to create a warning message, but in the result the warning message comes before the "Warning message:" part. Is there a different way to create this warning message so that it is printed after "Warning message:"?
This is what the output looks like:
> acceptable_classes <- c(
+   "character", 
+   "gg", 
+   "ggplot", 
+   "data.frame", 
+   "flextable"
+ )
> 
> # This prints the correct way:
> if(TRUE){
+   warning("Some result is not an acceptable class.")
+ }
Warning message:
Some result is not an acceptable class. 
> 
> # This prints backwards:
> if(TRUE){
+   warning(
+     cat(
+       "Some result is not an acceptable class.",
+       "Acceptable classes are:", 
+       acceptable_classes, 
+       sep = "\n"
+     )
+   )
+ }
Some result is not an acceptable class.
Acceptable classes are:
character
gg
ggplot
data.frame
flextable
Warning message:


Why are you using cat()? If you just want to build a string, use paste() rather than cat(). The cat() function is for forcing text to the console. You wouldn't want to do that when building a warning message.

cat() prints. That’s all it does. You want sprintf() or paste() or something similar.

As mentioned in comments, you should avoid using cat, use paste instead, for example:
acceptable_classes <- letters[1:5]

if(TRUE){
  warning(
    paste(
      "Some result is not an acceptable class.",
      "Acceptable classes are:", 
      paste(acceptable_classes, collapse = ", "), 
      sep = "\n"
    )
  )
}

The result is:
Warning message:
Some result is not an acceptable class.
Acceptable classes are:
a, b, c, d, e 


warning will print all strings passed to ..., so you don't even need paste. A toString() call will handle the comma separation of the acceptable classes.
acceptable_classes <- letters[1:5]
if(TRUE){
  warning(
    "Some result is not an acceptable class.\nAcceptable classes are:\n", 
    toString(acceptable_classes)
  )
}
# Warning message:
# Some result is not an acceptable class.
# Acceptable classes are:
# a, b, c, d, e 

